# Create the "Timeline Photos" album using Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

## What I Want

I need to create the posts on a page wall with a big preview pictures - like the ones that are displayed when you upload a photo. It will make sense to add those photos to the "Timeline Photos" album of a user (or page) using the Facebook Graph API.

Sure I can poll the users albums list and search for a `type:"wall"` one (i.e. the *Timeline Photos* in the English translation), but what if the album does not exist? How do I create one or how do I make Facebook Graph create it?

## What Have I Tried

Tried posting to `/me/feed` with a message and a picture URL (params `picture` or `source`), but all it does is just create a `type:"link"` post with a small picture, while what I need is a `type:"photo"` one.

Once again, I need that because of the big photo that gets displayed on a wall if post is a photo. For instance, that happens when I upload a picture to the album that gets automatically created for my application. But the issue is that when there are several photos posted one after another, Facebook automatically groups them in a set that belongs to an album.

## P.S.

Basically, what I want to achieve is having an ability to send the posts to a page wall with big preview photos on the wall itself that are not grouped by an album name.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by posting a photo to `/{page-id}/photos`.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/photos

Comment: It should be noted that this solution does indeed resolve the issue for a Facebook Page, but does not address the problem for a specific user's "Timeline Photos".  The only solution I've come across for that problem is the "poll the users albums list" suggested in the original question (which I agree is not ideal).